# Developing a web/desktop app on an android device

Tags: android, java, software-development, ide

Are there tools that allow one to do professional development on a mobile device (specifically android)? The things I'm looking for are:

- I'm looking to develop a Java web application that will however be self contained using an embedded server which means it will end up being deployed as a `.jar` file and there won't be a need to start any type of web server.
- Writing code in a fast and efficient manner (code completion, jumping between files, snippets). I'm fine with something like Vim with plugins that support such functionality.
- Compiling and building the application as well as deploying it.
- Debugging the application (probably using a remote debugger)
- Viewing it in the installed web browser
- Using a build tool (`maven`) for dependency management and building / deployment
- Committing and pushing code to github repository

Is this doable in a mobile device? I believe it should be doable if everything is done remotely using cloud services but I'm looking to for a local solution at first (or partially local, for example developing on mobile and building in a cloud service?).

EDIT:

The application will also need to access a Database (probably SQL) in order to manage data but I believe deploying it on the mobile device is stretching it too far. This however can be solved by accessing it remotely (on a personal machine or a VM in a cloud service).

Comment: Not updated for a while (well, since 2013), but there's [Terminal IDE](http://www.appbrain.com/app/terminal-ide/com.spartacusrex.spartacuside) covering that – so possible it is. I've not tried any of them, but up-to-date is e.g. [AIDE](http://www.appbrain.com/app/aide-ide-for-android-java-c/com.aide.ui) and [Anacode](http://www.appbrain.com/app/anacode-ide-android-c-c-java/com.majosoft.anacode). For more candidates, you can [check here](http://www.appbrain.com/search?q=java+ide) – while waiting for good recommendations. Found a hit? Please answer your own question then :)

Comment: AIDE looks like the one I want but I cannot answer the question without trying it out first which will probably take some time. If someone with experience on the matter wants to post an answer, it would be better

Comment: Agreed – for the same reason I've just mentioned it in a comment. Whoever is first shall take the medal :) As I'm no dev, it won't be me. Enjoy!